# Логическая задач "Определить фамилии друзей"?

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog

В спортивный лагерь приехали три друга: Миша, Володя и Петя.
Известно, что каждый из них имеет одну из фамилий: Иванов, Семенов, Герасимов.
Миша не Герасимов, отец Володи инженер. Володя учится в 6 классе. Герасимов учится в 5 классе. Отец Иванова слесарь.
Определить фамилии друзей.

```
name(misha).
name(vova).
name(petya).
last_name(ivanov).
last_name(semyonov).
last_name(gerasimov).

% Миша не Герасимов
full_name(misha,X) :- 
last_name(X),
X \= gerasimov.

%профессии отцов
profession(ingeneer).
profession(locksmith).

father(vova,ingeneer).
father(ivanov,locksmith).

% номера классов   
num(five).
num(six).      
% Вова в шестом, Герасимов в пятом
class(vova,six).
class(gerasimov,five).
```

Как составить взаимоисключающие утверждение для Вовы: "Если Вова  учится в пятом, а Герасимов в шестом, значит Вова не Герасимов".